# Undefined Reference error with RGBD.hpp file from opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I've got a problem at the moment...

I've got a cmake file that includes the local computer files.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(testproject)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -pthread -Wall -fPIC -Ofast -fopenmp")

link_directories(/usr/local/lib/cmake)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/include)
set(LIBRARY_USR_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/include)

add_executable(testproject 
    "base.cpp"
    "Libraries/include/base64/base64.h" 
    "Libraries/include/base64/base64.cpp"
)
target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${LIBRARY_USR_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${LIBRARIES} ${LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} "${OpenCV_LIBS}"  stdc++fs)
```

The include file within CMAKE works because there are other files with opencv included and those are found..

Only the weird problem is that the **rgbd.hpp** (File is under /usr/local/include/) is found and also the function but when i'm making the the file with.

**Terminal Process:**

```
make -j7

ERROR RESULT:
[ 15%] Linking CXX executable count
CMakeFiles/count.dir/base.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/testpc/Documents/Test/base.cpp:10: undefined reference to `cv::rgbd::DepthCleaner::DepthCleaner(int, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/count.dir/build.make:374: recipe for target 'count' failed
make[2]: *** [count] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:94: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/count.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/count.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

That this happens when all the other files are already have been compiled.

Problem class: **Base.cpp**

```
#include "opencv2/rgbd.hpp"

int main() 
{
    rgbd::DepthCleaner * depthc = new rgbd::DepthCleaner(CV_16U, 7, rgbd::DepthCleaner::DEPTH_CLEANER_NIL);
}
```

**Possible Tried Solutions:**
Still having the same result, When i remove the content within the main method and replace it with `cout << "Test" << endl;` It builds and runs as it suppose to be. Also works when I create a new raw Material blanko with standard Opencv core included.

It only does not build with the RGBD Include and instance creation.

**(RGDB.hpp does not stand under /usr/local/inlclude) but under /usr/include. So i removed the local part but still responded as the same current issue. Any other possible solution?**

Comment: `set(LIBRARY_USR_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/include)` this does literally nothing on its own. Post your _full_ CMakeLists.txt or there is no way to help you.

Comment: @AlexReinking Added the full CMakeLists.txt

Comment: In `CMakeLists.txt` you define the executable target named `count`, but apply `target_include_directories` and `target_link_libraries` to the target `${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}`, which, according to the line `project(testproject)`, is `testproject`, not a `count`. Generally, when ask a question on Stack Overflow, substitution of automatic variables like `${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}` could be avoided in favor of **literal strings**. Using search on your question body, we could easily check that build paths corresponds to the literal name. But comparing it to `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME` could be not so easy.

Comment: Still having the same result, When i remove the content within the main method and replace it with ```cout << "Test" << endl;``` It builds and runs as it suppose to be. Also works when I create a new raw Material blanko with standard Opencv core included. 

It only does not build with the RGBD Include and instance creation.

**(RGDB.hpp does not stand under /usr/local/inlclude) but under /usr/include. So i removed the local part but still responded as the same current issue. Any other possible solution?** @Tsyvarev